# I am trying to print information from a json file with python

Tags: python, json

I have this .JSON file that tells what food there will be during the week in our school.(Sorry it's in Swedish)

Here is the JSON file

```
{
  "feedbackAllowed": "True",
  "weeks": [
    {
      "days": [
        {
          "date": 1647820800,
          "items": [
            "Korv Stroganoff serveras med ris",
            "Vegetarisk Stroganoff med sojakorv serveras ris"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": 1647907200,
          "items": [
            "Pasta serveras med laxsås",
            "Vegetarisk pastasås"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": 1647993600,
          "items": [
            "Morotslasagne med keso och soltorkad tomat",
            "Kökets klimatsmarta rätt ( vegetarisk lasagne)"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": 1648080000,
          "items": [
            "Het kycklingsoppa serveras med mjukt bröd och ost samt frukt",
            "Vegetarisk nudelsoppa serveras med mjukt bröd och ost samt frukt"
          ]
        },
        {
          "date": 1648166400,
          "items": [
            "Quorngryta med chili serveras med ris",
            "Kökets klimatsmarta rätt"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "number": 12,
      "year": 2022
    }
  ],
  "school": {
    "URLName": "XXX",
    "id": 000,
    "district": {
      "province": {
        "URLName": "XXX",
        "id": 000,
        "name": "XXX"
      },
      "URLName": "XXX",
      "id": 000,
      "name": "000"
    },
    "name": "000"
  },
  "id": 000,
  "bulletins": [
    {
      "text": "XXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am looking for is a way to only print out the "items"(all of them) from the JSON file. I have watched many tutorials and i keep getting errors like:

```
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable
```

etc.

i tried using this

```
import json
with open('filename.json', 'r') as input:
    obj = json.load(input)
    #make it a string the item is the first one
    #cool
    print(str(obj['items']))
```

but i got this error:

```
KeyError: 'items'
```

Comment: A side(might be the main one) note: Do not use `input` as the variable name, since it has been predefined in python for getting input from users through the console.

Comment: Your JSON file does not have a key named `items`. This key exists in the inner dictionaries. For example `weeks->days->items`. Therefore you need to call something like :`print(str(obj['weeks']['days']['items']))`

Comment: `weeks` and `days` are lists, you need to index them.

Comment: If you want to print all the items, you need to loop over all the weeks and days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over all the weeks and days.

```
for week in obj['weeks']:
    for day in week['days']:
        print(day['items'])
```

Comment: By the way, when the output is printed it will come out like this: ['<info>']. Is there a way to print with out the brackets and the quotes?

Comment: `print(*day['items'], sep="\n")` will print each item on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

So the `items` property you're trying to access is nested deeply within the JSON structure. As Barmar has correctly pointed out, you'll have to first step inside the weeks array, and then the days arrays within each week in order to access the objects that has "items" property.

obj > weeks > days > items

For loops will be your best friend to print out these properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access them like this. Just navigating down the dicts and lists

```
for i in range(len(obj['weeks'][0]['days'])):
    print(obj['weeks'][0]['days'][i]['items'])
```